# zend naviagtion not working due to zend route

Tags: zend-framework

**EDIT::**
the problem was caused due to zend route please check updates

I am using xml file for navigation.

EDIT::the following code is from layout.phtml file

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/adminnav.xml', 'nav');
$container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
$this->navigation()->setContainer($container);
echo $this->navigation();
```

when i am in my edit page, all don't any menu link. all get is /admin/controller/edit/ everywhere on menu item. any idea?

my edit action takes id, if id is not supplied then it will generate and error. however add and list method works fine

UPDATES::

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<nav>
    <home>
        <label>home</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <home>
                <label>home</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>home</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </home>
            <help>
                <label>help</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>home</controller>
                <action>help</action>
            </help>
        </pages>
    </home>
    <page>
        <label>pages</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <static>
                <label>static pages</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>page</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </static>
            <editpage>
                <label>static pages</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>page</controller>
                <action>edit</action>           
            </editpage>
        </pages>
    </page>

    <destination>
        <label>destinations</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <list>
                <label>list all</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>destination</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </list>
            <featured>
                <label>featured</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>destination</controller>
                <action>featured</action>                   
            </featured>
            <add>
                <label>add destination</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>destination</controller>
                <action>add</action>
            </add>
            <editdest>
                <label>edit destination</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>destination</controller>
                <action>edit</action>           
            </editdest>
        </pages>
    </destination>

    <tours>         
    <label>tours</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <list>
                <label>list tours</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>tour</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </list>
            <featured>
                <label>featured tours</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>tour</controller>
                <action>featured</action>
            </featured>
            <add>
                <label>add tours</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>tour</controller>
                <action>add</action>
            </add>
            <edittour>
                <label>edit tours</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>tour</controller>
                <action>add</action>
            </edittour>
        </pages>
    </tours>

    <hotels>            
    <label>hotels and resort</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <list>
                <label>list hotel</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>hotel</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </list>
            <add>
                <label>add hotel</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>hotel</controller>
                <action>add</action>
            </add>
            <edithotel>
                <label>add hotel</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>hotel</controller>
                <action>add</action>
            </edithotel>
        </pages>
    </hotels>

    <message>           
        <label>message</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <all>
                <label>all message</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>message</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </all>
            <contactus>
                <label>contact</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>message</controller>
                <action>contact</action>
            </contactus>
            <inquiry>
                <label>inquiry</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>message</controller>
                <action>inquiry</action>
            </inquiry>
            <reservation>
                <label>reservation</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>message</controller>
                <action>reservation</action>
            </reservation>
        </pages>
    </message>

    <advertisement>         
        <label>advertisement</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <list>
                <label>list ads</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>advertisement</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </list>
            <add>
                <label>add ads</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>advertisement</controller>
                <action>add</action>
            </add>
            <editad>
                <label>edit ads</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>advertisement</controller>
                <action>edit</action>
            </editad>
        </pages>
    </advertisement>

    <setting>           
        <label>settings</label>
        <uri>#</uri>
        <pages>
            <view>
                <label>view</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>setting</controller>
                <action>view</action>
            </view>
            <account>
                <label>account setting</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>setting</controller>
                <action>account</action>
            </account>
            <site>
                <label>site setting</label>
                <module>admin</module>
                <controller>setting</controller>
                <action>site</action>
            </site> 
        </pages>
    </setting>
</nav>
</config>
```

UPDATE::route for the edit action on bootstrap.php

```
    $frontcontroller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontcontroller->getRouter('router');

    //add route  for edit page so that pageid is not displayed in the url
    $router->addRoute(
        'edit-page',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin/page/edit/:pageid', array(
            'module' => 'admin',
            'controller' => 'page',
            'action'    => 'edit',
            'pageid'    => 'pageid'
        ))
    );
```

UPDATE::to Phil

```
<editdest>
    <label>edit destination</label>
    <module>admin</module>
    <controller>destination</controller>
    <action>edit</action>   
    <route>12</route>       
</editdest>
```

Error for this::

```
Fatal error: Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route 12 is not defined in
/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/HelperAbstract.php 
on line 522
```

Comment: As I understand, navigation is working in add and list actions, but it does not work only in edit action, yes? Does the menu is the same for all the actions (i.e. edit, list, add)? Could you also provide additional code snippets, e.g. from your edit action, add action (since it works), your xml file.

Comment: Show us the XML. Please format your question. Why don't you use capital letters?

Comment: @Marcin the menu is same for all actions, it is loaded from layout file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are any static routes involved, you need to set the route name on all navigation pages. This is because the navigation view helper uses the Url view helper to create links.

If there is no route name present, it uses the current route.

If the current route is a static one, it will only ever resolve to one URL, no matter what parameters are thrown at it.

Comment: yes there is a route present but it think it is not static. please see edit above

Comment: @explorex in any case, try setting a route name on each navigation page in your xml config, even if it's just <route>default</route>

Comment: @Phil i tried as you suggested and i got error. please details above

Comment: @explorex. Instead of <route>12</route> just add <route>default</route>

Comment: @Phil i don't get the new error, but i am back to my same old problem. Phil, tell me last thing, am i getting this problem due to route or navigation

Comment: @Phil okay my problem is solved, i was due to route. if if you have any other way to do this with route then please you are most appreciable to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the route you defined in `$router->addRoute`.

It should be:

```
$router->addRoute(
    'edit-page',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin/page/edit/:pageid', array(
        'module' => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'destination',
        'action'    => 'edit',
        'pageid'    => 'pageid'
    ))
);


<editdest>
    <label>edit destination</label>
    <module>admin</module>
    <controller>destination</controller>
    <action>edit</action>   
    <route>edit-page</route>
    <params>
       <pageid>12</pageid>
    </params>       
</editdest>
```

If you need different edit links on each page, you have to update the params in navigation container dynamically, i.e.:

```
// (pseudocode, not tested)
$this->navigation()->getContainer()->findOneByLabel('edit destination')->params->pageid = 12
```

Comment: i found out that i was an error due to route. please check route update. if you have any suggestion then it would be highly appreciable

Comment: @explorer Which is your actual question?