# has url routing got issue with zend navigation?

Tags: zend-framework

i have a url

```
htpp://localhost/siteroot/public/controller/action/id/10/name/name
```

i wanted to make it look more cool so i added this line of code in my bootstrap.php

```
    $frontcontroller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontcontroller->getRouter('router');

    //add route  for edit page so that pageid is not displayed in the url
    $router->addRoute(
        'edit-page',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('page/edit/:pageid/:pagename', array(
            'controller' => 'page',
            'action'    => 'edit',
            'pageid'    => 'pageid',
                            'pagename'      => 'pagename'
        ))
    );
```

Everything worked fine just for navigation.

I am loading navigation from layout.phtml file using an xml file that works just fine if url is not routed. please see it here [zend naviagtion not working due to zend route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817294/zend-naviagtion-not-working-due-to-zend-route) where i had to re-edit and re-edit but so when then source of the problem was traced, question was not so specific and stale.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update XML too:

```
 <editpage>
        <label>static pages</label> 
        <module>admin</module>
        <controller>page</controller>
        <action>edit</action>           
        <route>edit-page</route>
 </editpage>
```

#### Update after comment:

Other pages need to have:

```
<route>default</route>
```

Comment: thanks!! but you might wanna edit your answer again. if i add <route>default<route> (except that piece of code on edit menu) on every one of my menu item, then it works perfectly!